# Convert list of maps into one single map

Tags: elixir

How could a list of maps like `some_maps = [%{"test" => [1]}, %{"test2" => [2]}, %{"test" => [3]}]` be converted to one huge single map with it's values merged?

```
single_map = %{"test" => [1, 3], "test2" => [2]}
```

Since I cannot modify a map within an iteration like `for` I dont know how to build this map

In other language I would define an empty map and iterate through the list and fill the map but functionally thinking I dont see how I could do this.

Comment: The answer for these questions where you want to iterate and change something is always `Enum.reduce`. :) All of the other functions in the Enum module are implemented on top of it. I can post the complete answer but I think you would learn more if you tried to solve it Enum.reduce first.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying with reduce but couldnt figure out, I will keep trying, it's hard to think on functional way :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
Enum.reduce(some_maps, fn x, y ->
   Map.merge(x, y, fn _k, v1, v2 -> v2 ++ v1 end)
end)
```

Answer (score 5):

The reduce solution is definitely the production-quality answer.  However, since you mentioned the difficulty you are having with functional programming, consider the 'long-hand' version of the reduce:

```
defmodule MapMerger do
  # The api function takes a list of maps, and returns them merged together.
  def merge(list_of_maps) do
    # This is written with a second function to hopefully be easier to follow;
    # these two functions could be collapsed using a default parameter
    # for the accumulator.
    do_merge(list_of_maps, %{})
  end

  # This is the base case, which will match after all maps have been processed
  # and the list is empty:
  defp do_merge([], acc), do: acc

  # Next comes the actual iterator; we pull head (the first item in the list),
  # process it, then recurse on the rest of the list and an updated accumulator
  defp do_merge([head|rest], acc) do
    updated_acc = Map.merge(acc, head)
    do_merge(rest, updated_acc)
  end
end
```

Once you can follow this, reduce should easier to think about- it doesn't modify anything, it just keeps recursing with new parameters that happen to be updated versions of the old parameters.  My production code usually uses `reduce` for small work like this, but when the operation inside the reduce is complicated, I usually decompose the reduce to a proper function that is easier to reason about, and easier to mark up with comments.

From your original question:

> In other language I would define an empty map and iterate through the list and fill the map

Note that this is a reasonable description of how the `merge` and `do_merge` functions above work.  You aren't as far away from thinking functionally as you believe.